# Refresh ListView upon Tab change/swipe (Android)

Tags: android-listview, android-fragments, adapter, .refresh

I have a Fragment and a ListFragment both under a FragmentActivitiy.  When I am in the Fragment, and I want to swipe to the ListFragment, how do I get the ListView to update?

Basically, I have an insert button/EditText in the Fragment and the user will insert new info.  I want to swipe to the ListFragment and then dynamically SEE that new info.  The only way to get it to refresh is by backing out of the parent activity and entering again.

I see there are methods onTabSelected or onTabReselected, not sure if this is where you do it?

Would it involve the typical code "Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()"?

Edit:  I am thinking maybe I just need to see how you can update a Fragment view in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I answered my own question:

I have this code

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


}
```

Comment: Hi KickingLettuce, I am stuck with same kind of issue. Can you please post your ListFragment code and Tab Listener code. It will be very helpfull

Comment: Sorry I can't really help now.  I have redesigned this app so many times I don't even have this code.  I think what I end up doing was just moving the `EditText`  / Submit `Button` to the same side as the `ListFragment` and then on submit, refreshed the `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I have solved this issue using Broadcast receiver.